# Django private messages notification

Tags: django

How this real time notification works? Something like notification in Facebook.

I have a webpage in Django. And user A send a message to User B. And this works in my project but user B see the message notification (You have a message) onlny when he refreshes the page.

How to do this in real time? User A send a message, user B has opened webpage and when message has been sent User B automaticaly see that he has new message (without refresh the page).

I can send a ajax request every second from client to server to 'ask' server that does client have a new message. But I think - this is not much efficient and there is a best way to do this.

Comment: Use websockets. Django-channles is the project that supports them. And they even have example with implementing web chat: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html

Comment: Django-channels is great, as an alternative you can look into something like pubnub or firebase for your realtime components. In *some* cases, they may be more useful.